# $1$-form of a antiholomorphic function, Cauchy-Goursat Theorem

Tags: complex-analysis, analysis

> Let be $f:U\to \Bbb C$ antiholomorphic function. Show that the 1-form
>   $f(z)d\overline{z}$ is closed.

We have that $\overline{f}$ is a holomorphic function, so by Cauchy-Goursat Theorem the 1-form $\overline{f}(z)dz$ is closed. But, how can I conclude that $f(z)d\overline{z}$ is closed?

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Differentiation is a real operator, that is, it commutes with conjugation,

$$d\overline{\omega} = \overline{d\omega}$$

for every $k$-form. Since you know that $\overline{f(z)}\,dz$ is closed, i.e. $d\bigl(\overline{f(z)}\,dz\bigr) = 0$, the result follows.

Alternatively, use the Wirtinger derivatives,

$$dg = \frac{\partial g}{\partial z}\,dz + \frac{\partial g}{\partial \overline{z}}\,d\overline{z},$$

and note that $f$ being antiholomorphic means $\frac{\partial f}{\partial z} = 0$, so

$$d\bigl(f(z)\,d\overline{z}\bigr) = \bigl(df(z)\bigr)\wedge d\overline{z} = \biggl(\frac{\partial f}{\partial z}(z)\,dz + \frac{\partial f}{\partial \overline{z}}(z)\,d\overline{z}\biggr)\wedge d\overline{z} = 0.$$

Comment: Been using these things for years now, and I never did know they are called Wirtinger derivatives -- till I stumbled across your answer. Strangely enough, this fact is not mentioned in any of the complex analysis texts I've used. Thanks.